# Apache Tomcat deployed service not using java truststore?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl-certificate

I am trying to make a HTTP POST request to a server with https. When I was testing making the call I did it on a standalone java program (not deployed on a server) and initaially got the error:

```
 unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

however I fixed this with creating a cacert using a tool online called InstallCert and pointing java there with:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\Users\\...\\jssecacerts");
```

However, when I implement the same fix in the code that I deploy on Apache Tomcat it doesnt work and I get the same error as before. So my question is do .war files deployed on Apache Tomcat use a different trust store than the java one? Or do they not use the system properties? How can I get Apache Tomcat to use the cacert?

Thanks

EDIT:

So I've tried to do some more research and get it fixed with no success. I tried following http://andyarismendi.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/changing-tomcats-ca-trust-keystore-file.html to try and get it fixed.

Changing the server.xml file made no difference. However, changing the Tomcat Java Options with

```
-Djavax.next.ssl.trustStore="myFile"
```

Altered the response that I got, with this I get:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned response code 500 for URL websitesURL
```

I also saw in some places that copying the jssecacerts file into my jre\lib\security directory could fix this. However this just cause the response code 500 error...

This is the code that is being used to make the POST Request:

```
//System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\file\\path\\jssecacerts");
    try
    {   
        OAuthClient client = new OAuthClient(new URLConnectionClient());

        //grant_type=password
        OAuthClientRequest.TokenRequestBuilder trb = new OAuthClientRequest.TokenRequestBuilder(TOKEN_URL)
                .setGrantType(GrantType.PASSWORD)
                .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
                .setUsername(username)
                .setPassword(password);

        OAuthClientRequest ocr = trb.buildBodyMessage();
        ocr.setHeader("Authorization", base64EncodedBasicAuthentication(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET));

        String responseBody = client.accessToken(ocr, OAuthJSONAccessTokenResponse.class).getBody();
        return responseBody;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.getMessage();
    }
```